# Spring Integration Testing Oracle Native SQL

Tags: spring, oracle, testing, integration, in-memory-database

I have a legacy application that has recently been ported from Struts to Spring MVC. The data layer is written with native Oracle SQL. I'd like to introduce some integration testing but would like to avoid using an actual Oracle database for obvious reasons. Is there an in-memory DB that can deal with Oracle native SQL? Is this just a dream? Am I just going to end up with Oracle XE in a VM?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the reasons for wanting to do integration testing without an actual database are not so obvious . . . I can't even begin to imagine how one might test a database application without a database ...

Comment: @EdStevens I guess the reasons for not wanting an actual Oracle database of Integration testing aren't so obvious. 1) having to manage a centralized schema for integration 2) network latency 3) sharing a database with multiple people doing Integration testing. I'm sure there are more reasons, but those are the first that come to mind.

Comment: @EdStevens I have worked on MongoDB based applications that had integration tests that could be run offline and by multiple developers without requiring a common DB configuration external to the app code. It was almost trivial to have an in-memory MongoDB instance to run tests against.

Comment: "It was almost trivial to have an in-memory MongoDB instance to run tests against."  So you DO have a database to test against ("an in-memory MongoDB instance").  You just architect it a bit differently.

Comment: @EdStevens, I was using my MongoDB instance as an example. This is a completely different project, one that is based on JDBC and Oracle native SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that H2 actually has an Oracle compatibility mode. Great!

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Oracle's in-memory database, TimesTen, compatible with standard Oracle?

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't know about TimesTen. Do you have an example of how I can define that inside a Gradle or Maven script?